# Phone Call Recording incoming sounds too low

Tags: android, voice-recording, incoming-call

```
 mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
            mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);

            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.GINGERBREAD_MR1) {
                mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC);
            } else {
                mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.DEFAULT);
            }
```

My problem is that when app starts to record a phone call, my mediaRecorder saves the call, but when I open it, my voice is clear and understandable. On the other hand, incoming voice is not clear and understandable. I tried to change `audiosource` which is `VOICE_CALL` and my mediaRecorder doesn't start. I also  gave permissions for `VOICE_CALL`. I tried other audio sources but none worked. Incoming voice is not clear. How can I fix this problem? My testing device is: General Mobile GM5 Plus and my android version is 6.0.1.

Comment: Did you got any solution. I am stuck here for the same with no solutions. Could you please help me.

Comment: There is no solutions about this problem. After Marshmallow, permissions of  recording voice call is forbidden unfortunately.

Comment: @GörkemKaradoğan but the ACR call recorder app working fine on Marshmallow. Anyone please help me on this issue.

Comment: I Also had the same issue but with noughat on Samsung Galaxy S7 please notify if there is any solution.